# Build app for distribution

Tags: ios, release, distribution, xcode4.3

I tried to build my project for distribution. I do it with help of this tutorial - http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/build.html

Step 3-b is to setting Developer Certificat in Code Signing sections: Debug, Release ans Distribution. But there is only Debug section in my Build Settings. How can i add 2 other? Thnx

UPD in my Project-Info-Configurations there is not "Release" configuration. How should i add it?
[image]

UPD 2 i expand rows in the very beginning. And there is only debug section

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT! In Xcode, navigate to your project in the file tree:

[image]

Select your PROJECT (not your target):

[image]

Select the Info tab:

[image]

Find the configurations tab, select the + button:

[image]

Select "release".

Comment: OK, you're in the wrong section of Xcode.  I will update my answer to help you more specifically.

Comment: yeah. i understand you. but you dont understand me. maybe i describe problem in the wrong way. on the second screenshot you can see that there is only on section in my Code Signing

Comment: When you select your project in the file tree, are you editing the settings for the project itself (blue icon), or your target?

Comment: can you explain very last step? when i press + there is only option "duplicate debug configuration". should i simple duplicate it and just renamed?

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'd make a new project.  Usually, they come with release and debug modes built in, unless you are editing the settings for the unit tests...

Answer (score 0):

You must have done step 2 wrong. You must have the wrong certificate. Publishing an app on the app store is a pain as you must have the right certificate for everything.